# Is there any rules in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

I was wonder is there any rules I need to follow in Firebase Realtime Database like in a normal table-style database? It is my first time using document-styled database. Is it I can structure my table on my own as long as there is no problem in retrieve and save data? Thanks in advance for everybody who guides me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database is a schemaless database. By default you can store any valid JSON data in it.

You can however control what data can be written by clients, by using Firebase's server-side security rules. These allow you to declaratively control both who can read/write data, and what data they can write.

For more on this, see:

- the [overview documentation on Firebase's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules)
- the [detailed documentation on security rules for the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)
- this [video on security rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEuu9X9L-MU), which is the first in a new series.